# How to properly format the derivative of a vector?

Tags: math-mode

When writing the derivative of a vector-valued function, I naively wrote:

```
\vec{r}'(t)
```

But when typeset, the prime collides slightly with the vector arrow.  What are the best practices here?

Comment: `\dot\vec{r}` -- it's a time derivative or a derivative with respect to a 'parameter' or `\vec{r}\,'`

Answer (score 3):

Only suggestions, since the question is a little bit opinion-based

The `\vec{r}'` is indeed too narrow -- using the `esvect` package and its `\vv` command provides a somewhat better spacing, however, the arrows are longer.

Alternatively using `\dot{\vec{r}}` is to be preferred in a `Physics' context if a time derivative or with respect to a parameter is indicated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

$\dot{\vv{r}}$

With dot and normal \verb!\vec!: $\dot{\vec{r}}$

With \verb!\,'!: $\vec{r}\,'(t)$

esvect style: $\vv{r}'(t)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `\vec{{}r}` or `\vec{\kern0pt r}` it looks better in this case.

Comment: @Manuel: Not really. The prime is too near to the arrow still.

Comment: I meant just versus the `\vec{r}` part.

Comment: Okey, I see that I wrote the same comment in form of an answer in the duplicate question. Sorry :)